# Best way to find SQL object dependencies in a C# program

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I have a program in C# that interacts with a couple different MS SQL databases. It, unfortunately, uses a mishmash of different methods to connect and query the databases (i.e., it has some .SQL files that it uses, but it also sometimes builds a query in a string and runs it using ExecuteScalar() ).

What's the best way to exhaustively, systematically find all database objects that are directly referenced by this program? (I don't care about indirect references like where the program calls a procedure and the procedure calls a function. I can figure out those dependencies just by looking at the database).

Comment: Figure out what the names of the principal accessor classes are, and do a global find on each of those.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any *easy* way.  You could find references to objects that reference the databases, or if your code always uses every SQL reference it contains each time it is run (pretty unlikely), you could profile the interaction between your program and the databases, but either way it will probably be a lot of work.